# PHP class not returning array when called

Tags: php, arrays, class, function

I have a PHP class which is supposed to return an array to where the object is instantiated. I have tried to figure out what the problem is but I can't seem to see it. 
Can anyone see where I have gone wrong here or point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Here is the class (within a file called 'feeds.php.)

```
class updateFeed {
public function index() {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tweets";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadObject()
        if(strtotime($result->date_added) <= time() - 3200) {
            $this->updateTweets();
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM tweets ORDER BY tweet_date DESC LIMIT 0, 3";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $results = $db->loadObjectList();

        $tweet_db = array();
        foreach($results as $result) {
            $tweet_db[] = array(
                'title'   =>   $result->title,
                'text'    =>   $result->text,
                'tweet_date'   =>   $result->tweet_date
            );
        }   
        return $tweet_db;

    }
```

And here is where the object is instantiated (in the index.php file):

```
include('feeds.php');
$tweet_dbs = new updateFeed;
print_r($tweet_dbs);
```

The print_r in the index file shows 'updateFeed Object ( ) '.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It simply should be `print_r($tweet_dbs->index());` as you never call the class-method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using your  class wrong. You do not call index() method.
Try this:

```
include('feeds.php');

// Create class instance
$instance = new updateFeed;

// Call your class instance's method
$tweet_dbs = $instance->index();

// Check result and have fun
print_r($tweet_dbs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
include('feeds.php');
$tweet_dbs = new updateFeed;
$tweets = $tweet_dbs->index();
print_r($tweets);
```

You missed to call the index() function..

Answer (score 0):

you need to call that method using object of the class.

replace

```
print_r($tweet_dbs)
```

with

```
print_r($tweet_dbs->index())
```

Comment: @insertusernamehere: I dont get you .

Comment: I guess what you actually wanted to say is: "*replace* `print_r($tweet_dbs)` *with* `print_r($tweet_dbs->index())`".

Comment: nope .. print_r($tweet_dbs->index())  with print_r($tweet_dbs)

Comment: But you changed it anyhow. ;)